# What ports should I node.js listen on? How and why?

Tags: node.js, http, https, port

My node.js applications I have listening on port 80 for http and 443 for https, which I believed was fairly standard practice.

However a number of examples I have read recently use other ports (e.g. 8080 and 8081) for listening to http/https, and then use other means such as `iptables` or `ufw` rules to serve ports 80 / 443 via rerouting packets to/from the others.

See two examples [here](https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/776580) and [here](https://gist.github.com/benatkin/939400).

So my question is **why would I not want to listen directly to ports 80 and 443?**

Are there security issues at hand? Is it simply a case of these authors not having permissions to listen on ports lower than 1024 (I'd find this surprising?)? Do most people run Apache along side node? (I do not).

Assuming there is a good reason for why I don't want to listen directly to 80 and/or 443, **which method should I be using to relay traffic from 80 / 433 to my alternative ports of choice?**

I have mentioned iptables and ufw above, is one of these better than the others, or is there some other method I should be using? Does the answer depend on whether I'm balancing my load between processes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think its becouse you need root rights to run on ports lower then 1024 and you dont want youre app to have root, there is however ways to bind it stil. i personaly use [AuthBind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind)

Comment: If I am not wrong, port 1337 is becoming a standard to run nodejs on. To execute applications, you can use NGINX as reverse proxy server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first line of the first article you linked to mentions the reason.

```
Standard practices say no non-root process gets to talk to
the Internet on a port less than 1024.
```

For node to bind to port `80` or `443`, you would need to run it as root, which is not a good idea.

The method you use to reroute traffic to the higher ports is up to you. The `iptables` is the least resource-intensive and simplest. Another method would be to use NginX/Apache to proxy to Node. I'd say the main benefit of that method is that you can then also serve things like static files from there, and not have to serve them through Node.

Apache and NginX are both designed explicitly to be very good at serving static files, so they are extremely good at it, whereas Node is a whole JS environment, with all the overhead that involved. Node is great at handing lots of simultaneous connections, and it can certainly serve files perfectly well for normal loads, but it will use more resources than NginX to do it.

Using an HTTP-aware proxy like Apache/NginX also means that you can very easily set up multiple instances of Node to run different subdomains, or even different paths on the same domain.

Comment: What benefits are there to using NginX/Apache to serve files rather than Node?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: but if you use the approach with Apache or NginX...that means, that these servers would need root-privileges in order to listen to port 80, right?.. so why isn't it a problem for them, but for node.js it is?

Comment: Those servers do not run as your user. When you start them, generally you are telling them to start, and then they switch to run as their own user, and the installation scripts for them have set up their users to have access those ports. You could do the same thing for your own user if you really wanted but most people run Node behind some proxy.