# What is nodejs express manage several domains?

Tags: node.js, express

I have got 2 domain names. For instance, example0.org and example1.org.
How to setup nodejs using express to manage both of them?
For instance, I wanna share

> /publicexample0

folder as root for

> example0.org

and

> /publicexample1

folder for

> example1.org

as root

This works just for a one domain:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: How about hiding it behind apache vhosts redirecting domain1 to path1 and domain2 to path2 on the same node server?

Comment: @OlegS. I do not think this is a good idea to use both apache and nodejs in the same machine.

Comment: Why is that not a good idea?

Comment: Actually I would run two separate node servers on different ports and an apache on a single standard port, but serving two separate domains via vhost. What's wrong with that? In fact, there is actually a question about this with a very sensible answer, which supports my idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939239/what-ports-should-i-node-js-listen-on-how-and-why/14939308#14939308

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you can do is to take advantage of the [HTTP host header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). It contains:

> The domain name of the server (for virtual hosting), and the TCP port
> number on which the server is listening. The port number may be
> omitted if the port is the standard port for the service requested.
> Mandatory since HTTP/1.1.

You can see its specification in the [RFC 2616 - HTTP v1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-128)

And obviously you could read the header out of your request in Express and make a decision based on its value.

```
router.get('/hello', function(req, res){
   var host = req.get('host');
   if(host === 'example0.org'){
    res.send(200,'Welcome from example0.org');
   } else if(host === 'example1.org'){
    res.send(200,'Welcome from example1.org');
   } else {
    res.send(200,'Welcome stranger');
   }
});
```

Comment: Do all of requests has reg.get('host') value? Even if I send just simple URL request ?

Comment: @trololo Did you read the RFC documentation that I shared above? Your answer is there, under the "host" section.

Comment: ok . Understood. How to manage static folders ? app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/public')); for both domains?