# range of ports that i can used in web sockets in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

hi i am working with a chat application using node js. I want to know the range of port number  i can use

```
var webSocketsServerPort = 1337;     
server.listen(webSocketsServerPort, function() {
  console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + webSocketsServerPort);
});
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939239/what-ports-should-i-node-js-listen-on-how-and-why

Comment: Yes I got the answer there....Thank you.. :-)

Comment: @JensB, canu just tell the range of permissible ports here ?